# How to sent complex data with multiple images using HttpClient.PostJsonAsSync() in windiows Application C#

Tags: c#, api, windows-forms-designer

I have developed a Desktop application in C# and developed API (C#) for sending data from client (database) to server (database).

**Query:**

I want to send complex data with multiple images from a client (database) to a server (database).

I am sending complex data with images to server database but I am unable to send more than five images. when I am adding more than 5 images API gives `500` error.
I am using `HttpClient.PostjsonAsSync()` method.
So please suggest me what is the issue?

I have tried to changes API request length and I am unaware of how to use multipart in this case. I want to send data and images.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You have to provide more data. Structure of your data and how you want to transfer etc. If possible provide sample data.

Comment: Are you passing a base64 string of images?

Comment: Yes, I am trying  to  send both way base64 and byte array.

Comment: Complex data structure:
Class SharedModel 
{
DataTable  Table1  {get;set}
DataTable Table2  {get;set}
DataTable Table3  {get;set}
List<byte[]> PhotoList {get;set}
} 
This is my data structure .I am sending this data to server db using api

Comment: The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the website's server, SO you should be looking at your server side code instead of client side

Answer (score 0):

Since it hits a error when you add more images i don't think its the code itself that is the issue but the server configurations. There is a limit on how much data can be sent with a request and depending on the size of the images you might hit that limit and you get the 500 error.

Maybe try to send them in multiple requests or tweak the server settings to handle more data in the request.

Comment: I ma sending 5 image with data but i am unable to sent more than five image with data ? You are  suggesting me like that  create multiple request  its impact on performance and it is not good way to sending multiple images.

Comment: I think it depends on the size of the images that is the issue here, so if possible try and reduce the size or see if you can configure the server settings.

When sending more than one request then let the client do it in separate threads and just wait for them to complete before moving on in the code.

Comment: I think so , I will check it and let you know.
Thanks.